# Audio waveform visualization when animating in blender

Tags: animation

So I'm trying to animate a scene and I was thinking, is there a way to see the visual waveforms of an audio in the timeline/dopesheet?

Editing in external software,- like premiere pro, makes it easy since you know what time a part of the audio starts by looking at the wave form of the audio channel.

I was wondering if Blender had a similar function?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the *Video Sequencer*, select the audio strip and enable *Display Waveform*:

[image]